# ckeditor 4.4 responsive image upload with old image plugin and custom filemanager to add srcset, sizes attribute

Tags: javascript, extjs, ckeditor, responsive-images, srcset

I have ckeditor 4.4, Old Image plugin (Not Image2), and I am using custom filamanager to upload files.

How can I add responsive images to ckeditor.
I mean, I have to add sizes and srcset attributes automatically to img tag.

**Image preview also should work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In Ckeditor config.js do handle onOk and onShow events

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var editor = ev.editor;
    var sizes = '(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw';

    //Check if its image dialog only
    if (ev.data.name == 'image') {
        //whenever image dialog is shown, show srcset urls in it (if a image has) and disable unnecessory styling fields
        dialogDefinition.dialog.on('show', function(e){
            var imgElement = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
            var dialogBox = e.sender;
            var srcOrSrcset = '';

            if ((srcOrSrcset = imgElement.getAttribute('srcset'))) {
                //This line is very important to handle show event, because there is no originalElement in dialogBox
                //Other wise it will throw `called setCustomData on null` from original Image.js @ line 306 plugin
                //https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image/dialogs/image.js
                dialogBox.originalElement = imgElement;
                dialogBox.originalElement.data('cke-saved-src', srcOrSrcset);
                
                //disable content elements, because no use of inline style in case of responsive image
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtHeight').disable();
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtWidth').disable();
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtBorder').disable();
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtHSpace').disable();
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtVSpace').disable();
                dialogBox.getContentElement('info','cmbAlign').disable();

                //dialog.preview is not exists yet, so delaying execution. meanwhile original image.js show handler will attach preview dialogBox
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    dialogBox.preview.setAttribute('srcset', srcOrSrcset);
                }, 0);
            }
        });

        //on click of ok button of image dialog, add srcset attribute to the selected img
        //srcset should be in specific format i.e. img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg
        //images should be seperated by comma followed by space (, )
        //default src will be first url of srcset
        dialogDefinition.onOk = function (e) {
            var dialogBox = e.sender;
            var imgUrl = dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtUrl').getValue();
            var altTxt = dialogBox.getContentElement('info','txtAlt').getValue();
            var imgHtml = '';
            var indexOfFirstUrlEnd;

            //If entered url is like srcset
            if((indexOfFirstUrlEnd = imgUrl.indexOf(', ')) > -1) {
                imgHtml = '<img src="' + imgUrl.substr(0, indexOfFirstUrlEnd) + '"' +
                    'srcset="' + imgUrl + '"' +
                    'alt="' + altTxt + '"' +
                    'sizes="' + sizes + '"/>';
            } else {
                //if its normal src url
                var style = dialogBox.getContentElement('advanced','txtdlgGenStyle').getValue();
                imgHtml = '<img src="' + imgUrl + '" alt="' + altTxt + '" style="' + style + '" />';
            }
            editor.insertElement(CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(imgHtml));
        };
    }
});
```

2) In myCustomFileManager.js I have

```js
var imageSrcOrSrcset = '';
if(urls.length > 1) {
    for (var key in urls) {
        imageSrcOrSrcset += ', ' + urls[key];
    }
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtHeight').disable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtWidth').disable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtBorder').disable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtHSpace').disable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtVSpace').disable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','cmbAlign').disable();
} else {
    imageSrcOrSrcset = urls['0'];
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtHeight').enable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtWidth').enable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtBorder').enable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtHSpace').enable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','txtVSpace').enable();
  dialog.getContentElement('info','cmbAlign').enable();
}
            
//pass url/urls to image properties dialog
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(params.CKEditorFuncNum, imageSrcOrSrcset);

//set preview in case of srcset (multiple urls)
if(urls.length > 1) {
    window.opener.CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().preview.setAttribute('srcset', imageSrcset);
}
window.close();
```